# DXA - Keyword Information in Page metadata

Tags: 2013, dd4t, dxa, dxa-java

We have associated a Category `Page Type` to our Page metadata. After publishing the Page when we try to retrieve the associated Keyword information we are not getting any value.

The data type in page meta is `map<String, String>`. Keyword object is converted to string and displayed as `org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.KeywordImpl@6c5fa73`. This is of no use and correct `pageType` is not displayed.

Please let us know how to use Category and Keyword in paga metadata of DXA pages. BTW we are using DXA 1.2 JAVA

Answer (score 2):

This is a Known Issue. See: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/21

Note that `PageModel.Meta` is mainly intended for generating HTML meta tags. If you want to use Page metadata in your Page View, you can also define (and register) your own Page Model (a subclass of `PageModel`) with additional properties and use DXA's semantic mapping to map those to Page metadata fields in CM.